# Updating my app programmatically doesn't work

Tags: java, android, installation, apk

I have following code to try to automatically update my App:

```
  updateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  updateIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(apkFile)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
  startActivity(updateIntent);
```

The apkFile contains the full path of a world readable APK-file with the new version of the running App.
My code starts the updater-Intent and I'll asked for a confirmation to install the app.
I give this confirmation and the system displays a status bar and says that the App will be installed, then it says that it was not possible to install the App, without any reason.

The log gives no further clue:

```
I/ActivityManager(   61): Starting activity: Intent { dat=file:///data/data/de.lucabert.mybackup/cache/MyBackup.apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress (has extras) }
W/InstallAppProgress(  327): Replacing package:de.lucabert.mybackup
I/ActivityManager(   61): Displayed activity com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress: 810 ms (total 810 ms)
D/dalvikvm(  294): GC_EXPLICIT freed 257 objects / 16648 bytes in 673ms
D/PackageParser(   61): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl53189.tmp
D/dalvikvm(   61): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6145 objects / 369824 bytes in 255ms
D/dalvikvm(  212): GC_EXPLICIT freed 102 objects / 6312 bytes in 130ms
I/InstallAppProgress(  327): Finished installing de.lucabert.mybackup
I/global  (  692): Default buffer size used in BufferedWriter constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
D/MyBackup(  692): Update successfully. Closing program
```

I'm running this code on the emulator, with Android API 8.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot
Luca Bertoncello

Comment: Please note that Google recently banned self-updating apps from the play store.

Comment: What does it mean? I don't want to add my App to Google PlayStore... I just want to have it updated when a new version is available on my server.

Comment: If you don't want your app in the store, it does not matter for you.

Comment: Well, it was a problem of the emulator... I tried the same code on my phone and it works... What I learned today: DON'T trust the emulator... :(